# Showing that if $Q = Q_1 + j Q_2$ is unitary then a block matrix is orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Q**

Show tha tif $Q= Q_1 + j Q_2$ is unitary where $Q_i\in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$, then the $2m \times 2m$ matrix

$$
Z = \begin{bmatrix}
Q_1 & -Q_2 \\
Q_2 & Q_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is orthogonal.

**A**

The distinction between orthogonal and unitary is *usually* that orthogonal implies that the transpose is the inverse while unitary implies that the hermitian is the inverse.

$$
\begin{align*}
Z^T Z &=
\begin{bmatrix}Q_1^T & Q_2^T \\ -Q_2^T & Q_1^T\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1 & -Q_2 \\
Q_2 & Q_1
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
Q_1^TQ_1 + Q_2^TQ_2 & -Q_2^TQ_2 \\
-Q_2^TQ_1 + Q_1^T Q_2 & Q_2^T Q_2 + Q_1^T Q_1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

My strategy is to look at what some of the terms evaluate to and then substitute those back in. So

$$
\begin{align*}
Q_1^TQ_1 &= (Q - jQ_2)^T(Q-jQ_2) \\
         &= Q^TQ -j Q^TQ_2 - j Q_2^T Q- Q_2^TQ_2
\end{align*}
$$

And as I keep working it I don't really see things cleaning up...

If I assume that by orthogonal the authors meant unitary I get

$Z^H Z = 2I$

Which isn't what we're going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are real, so $Z$ is also real, and its conjugate transpose is the same as the usual transpose.

$Q$ being unitary means $$I = Q^H Q = (Q_1 - jQ_2)^\top(Q_1 + j Q_2) = Q_1^\top Q_1 + Q_2^\top Q_2 + j(Q_1^\top Q_2 - Q_2^\top Q_1).$$
Which in turn implies
$$I = Q_1^\top Q_1 + Q_2^\top Q_2$$
$$0 = Q_1^\top Q_2 - Q_2^\top Q_1$$

This helps you reason about your block diagonal entries.

For the block off-diagonal entries, double check your matrix multiplication.

Comment: How do we know that $jQ_1^T Q_2 = jQ_2^T Q_1$?

Comment: @financial_physician Clarified some steps I skipped.